# jQuery FancyBox Rails 3.2.12 - Show Contents correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox-2

I have installed the FancyBox gem and followed the instructions as detailed on. [Fancy Box2](https://github.com/kyparn/fancybox2-rails). What I am trying to do should be quite trivial but is proving to be annoying.

In a .js file I have:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $(".lightbox").fancybox();
});
```

On my rails page I have:

```
<%= link_to 'Share Widget-Lightbox', widgetinvitation_path, :class => 'lightbox' %>
```

Pretty trivial right? What i am expecting is when I click on this link the lightbox appears with the contents of whats on this page. However instead it redirects me to the page..?

The `widgetinvitation_path` simply contains:

```
<div class="border-form-div">
  <h2> Invite user  </h2>

  <%= simple_form_for @user, :url => invitation_path(:user), :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>
      <%= select_tag :role_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Role.offset(3), 'id', 'name') %>
      <%= f.select :widget_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@widgets, "id", "name") %>

      <%= f.submit t("devise.invitations.new.submit_button") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So that on the parent page (where the FancyBox link exists) is I'd expect when I click on the link the form above is rendered in the fancybox. I am sure I am missing something basic. I have tested that FancyBox works. It does. If i use a basic `<a>` tag. To provide a working example:

```
<a class= "lightbox" id="single_1" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_b.jpg" title="Singapore from the air (Andrew Tan 2011)">
  <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

The above works but.. Not my `<%= link_to .... %>`

Generated HTML for `link_to`

```
<a href="/widgetinvitation" class="lightbox">Share Widget-Lightbox</a>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that's generated by the non-functioning `link_to`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FancyBox 2 appears to require hinting as to what sort of behavior is required for the link, since it can load content via Ajax, via iframe, or inline. The example works without any hinting because the code is specifically detecting things that look like images:

https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/blob/master/source/jquery.fancybox.js#L296

You'll need to either pass the hint as an extra class ('fancybox.ajax' or 'fancybox.iframe'), as a `data-fancybox-type` attribute on the link, or via a default in your configuration:

```
$('.lightbox').fancybox({type: 'ajax'});
```